# Translation of алгоритмическое обеспечение

Tags: перевод

I can't think of a good translation for **алгоритмическое обеспечение**. At first, I would have translated it as *mathematical software*, but this site https://studfile.net/preview/5443793/page:12/ states that **алгоритмическое обеспечение** is a component of **математическое обеспечение** (which I would also translate as *mathematical software*) along with **программное обеспечение** (I would translate this as *software*). It then goes on to say that **программное обеспечение** is made up of **общее обеспечение** (I would translate this as *system software*) and **специальное обеспечение** (which I would have translated as *application software* if it had not been for the fact that it breaks **специальное обеспечение** into **общесистемное** (I would translate this as *general purpose software*) and **прикладное программоне обеспечение** (I would translate this as *application software*). I realize there is not always a one-to-one translation for things; but that being said, I fail to see how **алгоритмичекое обеспечение** and **математическое обеспечение** are being differentiated. By the way, I provided the additional amplifying information (along with my translations) as I felt that it would help in trying to understand a good translation for **алгоритмические обеспечение**.

Comment: All depends on context. You need to understand why the original is using "алгоритмическое обеспечение" rather than more popular "программное обеспечение" and whether it matters.

Comment: may be, you can use algorithms, algorythmic ware, or, may be, make neologism by analogy with "software" - "algoware":>

Comment: Alexander, and JMP : it matters. Algorithms (in this context) are just the logic of the process, written in flowcharts or in another way, and don't represent itself a  software product created actually in machine commands (instructions CPU).   F.e. : https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

As the original says,

> Алгоритмическое обеспечение (АО) - это совокупность математических методов, моделей и алгоритмов, используемых в системе для решения задач и обработки информации.

By itself, обеспечение has a lot of meanings including *provision, supply, backup, maintenance, service, support* and many others (see e.g. this [Multitran page](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?s=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&l1=2&l2=1)).

I would probably go with **Algorithmic tooling**.